# How to Render Realm ListView with Sections Header

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm using react native with realm db. The realm schema is as follows:

```
  static schema = {
    name: 'TodoItem',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
      id: {type: 'string'},
      value: {type: 'string'},
      Category: {type: 'string'},
      completed: {type: 'bool', default: false},
      createdTimestamp: {type: 'date'}
    }
  }

export const todoItemDS = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2, sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2})

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  dataSource: todoItemDS.cloneWithRowsAndSections(todoItemsResults),
}
```

The ListView tag is as follows:

```
<ListView
          dataSource={dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader.bind(this)}
        />
```

and renderSectionHeader:

```
renderSectionHeader(sectionData, category) {
  return (
    <Text>{category}</Text>
  )
}

renderRow(item){
  const {dataSource, deleteTodoItem} = this.props
  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between',flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <CheckBox onPress={(e) => this.completed(item.id,item.value,e.target.checked)} style={{marginTop: 15 }}checked={item.completed} />
      <Text onPress={(e) => this.goToPageTwo(item.id)} style={{ alignSelf: 'center',flex:10}} >{item.value}
      </Text>
      <Button iconLeft large transparent primary style={{ height: 30 , flex:1 }} onPress={() => deleteTodoItem(item)}>
          <Icon name="trash-o" style={{ color: 'red' }} />
      </Button>
  </View>) 
}
```

I fill todoItems datasource from this function:

```
export const getTodoItems = () => {

  const todoItems = TodoItem.get().sorted('createdTimestamp', true);
  return todoItems
}
```

However, the rows and sections are rendered with empty sections text and empty rows text as shown in the image.

[image]

What is missing in this code and how can I render sections and rows correctly?

---

I added a listener to realm code that fills the data source as follows:

```
export const getTodoItems = () => {
  console.log('create db:', Realm.path)
  const itemData = {}
  const todoItems = TodoItem.get().sorted('createdTimestamp', true).filtered('completed=false');
  todoItems.addListener((items, changes) => {
  // Update UI in response to inserted objects
  changes.insertions.forEach((index) => {
    if(itemData[items[index].Category]) {
      itemData[items[index].Category].push(items[index])
    } else
      itemData[items[index].Category] = []//;
    });

  // Update UI in response to modified objects
  changes.modifications.forEach((index) => {

  });

  // Update UI in response to deleted objects
  changes.deletions.forEach((index) => {
    // Deleted objects cannot be accessed directly
    // Support for accessing deleted objects coming soon...

  });

});;

  todoItems.forEach((item) => {
    if(itemData[item.Category]) {
      itemData[item.Category].push(item)
    } else
      itemData[item.Category] = []//;
    }) 
  return itemData //todoItems
}
```

However, I can't see added items. The added item only shows up after adding another item. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us how you generate the `todoItemsResults` and what it looks like?

Comment: @dotcomXY I added the function that fills the data source.

Comment: So you can see the same amount of rows and correct amount of category rows get rendered and is just the content inside those Text component is empty?

Comment: @dotcomXY No. I added an image for what I see.

Comment: Can you share what is your renderRow function looks like?

Comment: @dotcomXY Added

Comment: I think is related to the same issue where you didn't construct your data source properly, see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The rendered SectionHeader is showing integer is because you didn't construct the dataSource in the right format, see the documentation here: [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html#constructor).

You need to construct something like:

```
const todoItemsData = {
  categoryOne: [itemOne, itemTwo],
  categoryTwo: [itemThree, itemFour]
}
```

But right now what you have is just an array of objects `[realmItemOne, realmItemTwo]`, and if you just pass in an array of objects to construct the dataSource that gonna consumed by the `cloneWithRowsAndSections`, the `category` param in `renderSectionHeader` will becomes integer index accroding to [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8117fa16c90c0462131f310e8e8f3290e229fc01/Libraries/Lists/ListView/ListViewDataSource.js#L197), Object.keys(arrayOfObjects) will return `[0, 1, 2, ...]`

So you want to map your `todoItemsResults` and construct the something like this

```
const itemData = {}
todoItemsResults.forEach((item) => {
  if(itemData[item.Category] {
    itemData[item.Category].push(item)
  } else
    itemData[item.Category] = [];
  }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  dataSource: todoItemDS.cloneWithRowsAndSections(itemData),
}
```

For the rendered row not showing any data issue, I think is due to the same problem, the `item` param you are calling within `renderRow` should be a data attribute for one of you todoItem object. You can try replace `{item.value}` within `{item}` to see what item is actually is in your setting. I believe this will be solved if you can construct the right data to feed your `dataSource`.

---

For your follow up comments regarding listerning to Realm update:
You can do something like this

```
class DummyPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.realmUpdated = this.realmUpdated.bind(this);
    realm.objects('todoItem').addListener('change', this.realmUpdated);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    realm.objects('todoItem').removeListener('change', this.realmUpdated);
  }

  realmUpdated() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    //build your data source in here and render the sectionList
  }

}
```

Comment: But in this case realm will not auto update the list view. Is there any other solution that can fix this problem?

Comment: @FerasOdeh, you can leverage Realm's listener mechanism:https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#notifications，to forceUpdate your page component. which will read the most update to date value from your Realm and re-render the list

Comment: I added my code for listening to notification. however, It is not working correctly. Can you please help?

Comment: @FerasOdeh I feel like that is worth opening another question, this one originally was just for figuring out why the SectionList is not rendering correct row and header section data. Open up another question would enable other people to contribute regarding the Realm auto-update issue.

Comment: @FerasOdeh Saw your updated edit, I think that won't work because the Realm change will recalculate and return the new itemData but it won't trigger the re-rendering of your page. So if you try follow my snippet above, remove your listner releated code in your `getTodoItems` and call `getTodoItems` inside render, and use the returned data to rebuild the dataSource, and have the Realm update to trigger the page forceUpdate, that should work.